# Can I move the notifications in IE 9 back to the top?

Tags: notifications, internet-explorer-9

As the title indicates, I'd like to move the notification area in IE9 to the top of my window.

My problem is that I've got my monitor in portrait mode for document browsing, and I've wasted several minutes out of my first hour of usage because I didn't notice the notification box at the bottom.  I'm back and forth between FireFox and IE (and will likely eventually be using Chrome as well), so a consistent UX is important.

[image: IE9 Notification Box]

Comment: What do you mean notification box? Can you link to a google image of what you mean?

Comment: Instead of notifications such as to "Download File" or "Run" appearing at top, it appears in a small yellow bordered box at the bottom of the IE9 window.

Comment: @arootbeer - No problem. :)  From my understanding you (currently) cannot move that box.  You're not alone in requesting this feature, and there may be a hack someone has come up with, but I wouldn't hold my breath. :)

Comment: That's fine too - I couldn't find that info anywhere.  Hopefully I can at least keep the search short for others :)

Comment: @arootbeer - Yeah, maybe if/when someone does figure out a way, or a new version of IE allows it, someone will come back here and update this with an answer other than "No, you can't". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of current there is no way to move it.

There have been many entries in the Microsoft Connect feedback for the ability to move this. So far every one has been closed with a rejection saying they won't fix it.

Although I would suggest putting in a feedback request anyways. I know several Microsoft employees and they have all told me that even though feedback request almost always get reject responses publically, internally they still track feature requests and if enough requests come in they will prioritize it on a list of review topics for future versions of products.